# Error when loading Jquery 2.1.4 file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little issue bugging me for several hours now, so i come to see you guys for some help.

Here is the situation :
I use jquery-2.1.4.js in my application. If i test my fragment of code outside the application it work correctly but when it is in my application Jquery doesn't load correctly.

Jquery is include correctly in my repository and called in my page before the end of the body tag like this (i moved it away from the head tag thiking it might be the issue but i still got the same error) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

I test if Jquery is correctly loaded like this :

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    // jQuery is not loaded
    alert("jquery not loaded,force it");
    var jq = document.createElement('script'); 
    jq.type = 'text/javascript';
    // Path to jquery.js file, eg. Google hosted version
    jq.src = 'js/jquery-2.1.4.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
} else {
    // jQuery is loaded
    alert("jquery is loaded");
}
```

The issue is here now :), everytime I end up in the not loaded part, and when I force Jquery load, I got an error line 3539 of the Jquery file on the function :

```
function Data() {
    Object.defineProperty( this.cache = {}, 0, {
        get: function() {
            return {};
        }
    });
    this.expando = jQuery.expando + Data.uid++;
}
```

With the error message :

This object does not have this property or method : defineProperty 
(not sure about the English for this one, my error message is in French).

Just so you know, there is no action done on Load, only when i click a button. Our file with JS codes are in a .include, so i don't know if this is why the error is trigger or not.

Anyway, thanks for taking the time to help me.

Slayner.

Comment: Do you have `expando` loaded? https://github.com/cantino/expando

Comment: i don't know the error message is on the Object.defineProperty it don't go till the load of expando.
By the way i don't even use this part of Jquery but it try to run it anyway.

Comment: `expando` is not part of jQuery, it is a plugin to jQuery. So besides loading, jQuery, you also need to load `expando`.

Comment: is he not suposed to load it by itself ? the run of this application is on localhost so he might not be able to donwload it if needed.

Comment: No, it will not load it by itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `expando` library, since it is not part of standard jQuery. Try adding this:

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/cantino/expando/38affee59bffdd87975c492472362c69ce0f6fda/jquery.expando.js"></script>
```

Right after this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question to ask @Slayner.

Comment: Okay my bad, i deleted my comment, i still got the same issue it was just taking is time to show me the error message, still the same by the way.

Comment: @Slayner, `Object.defineProperty()` is native JavaScript, perhaps you could test this in a different environment, like https://jsfiddle.net?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: well, it appears that if i don't inspect the element on the execution of the force load of jquery, there is no crash, but it sill prevent my call to Jquery with the function i wrote to work, nothing happens.

Comment: @Slayner, are you sure this is a valid path? `js/jquery-2.1.4.js`

Maybe try: `//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js`

Comment: the path is valid, other js are played like they should (i even try to use the Google repository of Jquery), my guess is from the button on the page that are on an include file launch at the load of this page, calling another include file where is the function calling Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the reason why this did not work for me was that our application is loaded as an IE5 application and is not compatible with JQuery (well not a version from these last few year.)